# Creating Aviary SDK Binding for Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin, aviary

I have fair enough knowledge of Xamarin iOS but I am naive to Monotouch Bindings.
I need to use Aviary SDK in my project and I understood by reading through that I need to follow below steps:

1. Create a Static project in Xcode, linking the Aviary SDK.
2. Create a Fat Binary file
3. Create a Binding Project in Xamarin
4. Add ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs
5. Add static library (the fat binary) in Binding Project
6. And so on.

But the problem is, I am stuck at the very initial step.
I followed this [Setup Guide](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide) but the issue is, thought I followed the steps, while Importing, I get this error:

> AviarySDK/AviarySDK.h file not found

I have downloaded the AviarySDK 4.0.1 which I downloaded from [here](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios).

**EDIT**
Thank you Jonathan Peppers, I have followed your steps, but for ApiDefinition.cs, as per the steps in followed [from](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/offline.pdf) I understood that I need to generate the ApiDefinition.cs from Objective Sharpie, but I get this error.

Can you help me on this?

```
In file included from /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:8:
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsGrunge = @"com.aviary.effectpack.01";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsNostalgia = @"com.aviary.effectpack.02";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsViewfinder = @"com.aviary.effectpack.03";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:37:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorProduct'
@interface AFPhotoEditorProduct : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:16:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFPhotoEditorEffectsIAPEnabledKey;
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:21:43: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol AFInAppPurchaseManagerDelegate <NSObject>
                                          ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:40:4: error: expected a type
- (NSString *)inAppPurchaseManager:(id<AFInAppPurchaseManager>)manager productIdentifierForProduct:(AFPhotoEditorProduct *)product DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:40:152: error: expected ':'
- (NSString *)inAppPurchaseManager:(id<AFInAppPurchaseManager>)manager productIdentifierForProduct:(AFPhotoEditorProduct *)product DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                                                                                                       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:51:35: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol AFInAppPurchaseManager <NSObject>
                                  ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:72: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AFInAppPurchaseManagerDelegate> delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                       ^
                                                                       ;
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:73: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AFInAppPurchaseManagerDelegate> delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:70:73: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isObservingTransactions) BOOL observingTransactions;
                                                                        ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h:62:73: error: cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AFInAppPurchaseManagerDelegate> delegate DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                        ^
1 warning and 18 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFInAppPurchaseManager.h.
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h:28:30: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFOpenGLManager'
@interface AFOpenGLManager : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h:34:40: error: expected a type
+ (void)setPurgeGPUMemoryWhenPossible:(BOOL)purgeGPUMemory;
                                       ^
2 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFOpenGLManager.h.
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:39:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorContext'
@interface AFPhotoEditorContext : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:45:41: error: unknown type name 'CGSize'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGSize size;
                                        ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:48:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isCanceled) BOOL canceled;
                                                           ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:51:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isModified) BOOL modified;
                                                           ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:58:41: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL hasBegunRendering;
                                        ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h:75:26: error: unknown type name 'UIImage'
- (void)render:(void (^)(UIImage *result))completion;
                         ^
6 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorContext.h.
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:14:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFEnhance;     /* Enhance */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:15:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFEffects;     /* Effects */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:16:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFStickers;    /* Stickers */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFOrientation; /* Orientation */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:18:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFCrop;        /* Crop */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:19:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFAdjustments;  /* Adjustments */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:20:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFSharpness;   /* Sharpness */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:21:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFDraw;        /* Draw */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFText;        /* Text */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:23:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFRedeye;      /* Redeye */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:24:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFWhiten;      /* Whiten */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:25:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFBlemish;     /* Blemish */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:26:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFMeme;        /* Meme */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFFrames;      /* Frames */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:28:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFFocus;       /* TiltShift */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:29:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFSplash;      /* ColorSplash */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:31:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetCancel; /* Cancel */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:32:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetBack;   /* Back */
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h:33:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetExit;   /* Exit */
       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.h.
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:17:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsGrunge = @"com.aviary.effectpack.01";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsNostalgia = @"com.aviary.effectpack.02";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:27:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
static NSString *const kAFProductEffectsViewfinder = @"com.aviary.effectpack.03";
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:37:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorProduct'
@interface AFPhotoEditorProduct : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:44:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productName;
^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:52:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *productDescription;
^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:39: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
                                      ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h:64:1: error: property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *internalProductIdentifier;
^
10 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorProduct.h.
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:10:8: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
extern NSString *const AFPhotoEditorSessionCancelledNotification;
       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:16:35: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'AFPhotoEditorSession'
@interface AFPhotoEditorSession : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:22:56: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;
                                                       ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:27:61: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
                                                            ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:32:60: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isModified) BOOL modified;
                                                           ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:44:51: error: expected a type
- (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
                                                  ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:55:51: error: expected a type
- (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image maxSize:(CGSize)size;
                                                  ^
/Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h:55:76: error: expected a type
- (AFPhotoEditorContext *)createContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image maxSize:(CGSize)size;
                                                                           ^
8 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/ramnathiyer/Documents/Projects/Aviary-iOS-SDK/AviarySDK-4.0.1/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AFPhotoEditorSession.h.
sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 1
System.Exception: sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 1
  at Sharpie.ObjC.Parser.Parse (System.IO.TextWriter sexpWriter, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 stderrLines) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Sharpie.Mac.MainWindowController+<GenerateBinding>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__B (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the SDK from their website (instead of Github), steps 1 and 2 are already done for you.

In the zip file, there is a `AviarySDK.framework` folder. This is where Obj-C libraries reside sometimes. The file in `Versions/A/AviarySDK` needs to be renamed to `AviarySDK.a` and added to a Xamarin binding project.

You will also need to add all the files in `AviarySDKResources.bundle` to your project or the library will probably not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I have followed your steps, but for ApiDefinition.cs, as per the steps in followed [from](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/offline.pdf) I understood that I need to generate the ApiDefinition.cs from Objective Sharpie, but I get this error. Can you help me on this?